# Propagating embedded Python Exceptions up to C++

Tags: python, c++, exception, embedding

If I have C++ code with embedded Python functions, *i.e.* it uses Python's C API to call Python's  interpreter, how can I get Python exceptions to bubble up to the C++ level?

---

*Note:* This is **not** the inverse question (about propagating C++ extension exceptions up to the Python intepreter).

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can just throw the class name of the python exception. Or are you asking how to even access in c++ the exception from the python call.

Comment: The Python exceptions being thrown contain informative messages, which I would like to print in the same way they are printed to the console in pure Python.

Comment: wait, so are you asking how to print the formatted traceback? Or just the exception itself. I think `Py_Print` with the `PyObject*` for the exception should do the latter.

Comment: Either one - I'm just not clear on how to get a reference to the exception object in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html

specifically, `PyErr_PrintEx(0)` -- this will print a traceback.

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering now if this is wrong. If you're using Py_Main or PyRun_*, it's likely you can't use PyErr_* to access exception info.

Comment: I think the OP means "how do I throw a C++ exception with the information in the Python exception?". At least, trying to find out how to exactly that is how I ended up here.